# Material ui contained button styling being overidden by MuiButtonBase-root

Tags: css, reactjs, button, material-ui

I am using material-ui with react. I have a simple contained button using

```
 <Button variant='contained' color='primary'> Edit</Button>
```

However the button does not look like a contained button. As seen in this screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYXaS.png).

Upon further investigation I found out the the .MuiButton-containedPrimary style is being overidden by the .MuiButtonBase-root styling as seen in this [screenshot taken from chrome dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MAy1.png).

Please can someone let me know how to fix this?

Answer (score 11):

This issue happened to me when part of my app relied on a component library that also used Material UI. My app and dependency used different versions of Material UI which led to the duplicated `.MuiButtonBase-root` style.

I solved this by moving `@material-ui/core` out of `dependencies` and into `peerDependencies` in my `package.json`.

This issue can also occur if you double nest an import. For example:

```js
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button/Button';  // Bad
```

Should be:

```js
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';  // Good
```

There's a very helpful thread on this issue in the Material-UI GitHub: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15610

Comment: Now is the right module: @mui/material/Button

Answer (score 0):

`.MuiButton-root` should be the one holding color code, not the `.MuiButtonBase-root`

Are your button example actually the one you use in your code? I can see that is has primary class which would imply usage of prop `color` which would result in:

```
<Button variant="contained" color="primary">
   Edit
</Button>
```

Recheck added `classNames` and determine which one is actually overwriting color.

Comment: Hi, Yes I did use the color='primary' prop I forgot to add it I've edited the question now

Comment: Yes I dont know why .MuiButtonBase-root is overriding the other styles and where its coming from ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have use new material i.e. mui and material-table. When I remove material-table everything is fine but with material-table something is overriding the styles.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Try to move **@material-ui/core** to devDependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.0",
```

and also add it to peerDependencies:

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.0"
},
```

It helped me to remove duplication of MuiButtonBase-root class